# Rails: simple bundler question with ruby-openid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-openid

I just installed the ruby-openid gem and then bundled it by entering

```
gem 'ruby-openid', :require => 'openid'
```

in the gemfile. Then I started bundle install and bundle lock. Everything worked fine so far.

But how can I now access the classes of ruby-openid.

```
OpenID::method
```

won't work for me. It raises a not found error.

What have I forgot or done wrong?

I'm absolutely new to bundler and the internet full of solutions for various versions, but I need one solution that's surely working.

I'm thankful for any help!

Comment: What output do you get if you run `bundle check`?

Comment: The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied